# Count number of distinct column combinations in R

Tags: r

I am looking for an easy way to count the number of
unique combinations in a big binary `matrix`.

If I have the following `matrix`:

```
m = matrix(c(1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

I would like to get the following output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    1    3
[2,]    1    1    1    1
```

So the function should count the number of unique combinations of columns - there are three rows that contains 1,0,1, and one row that contains 1,1,1.

The object type is not fixed (i.e. it can be a `data.frame`, `data.table`, whatever).
I would like to avoid having to specify the columns, to count over, by hand, 
if possible (i.e. i can supply a character vector with the corresponding column names, or use the whole matrix).

I know there has to be a solution, but my google fu seems to weak.

Comment: Where did `3` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `count` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
count(m, 1:ncol(m))

#  x.1 x.2 x.3 freq
#1   1   0   1    3
#2   1   1   1    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I've tried doing just that, and in the end
i had a name collision in the workspace.
It works perfectly